# Loading in multiple CSVs and storing them each in an individual array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm struggling to assign arrays to CSV files that I've loaded in. I'm using D3's `d3.queue()` method to load them in, but it seems like they're all being assigned to the same array.. Which isn't what i want.

```
var csvOne;
var csvTwo;
var csvThree;

var q = d3.queue();
    ['csv1.csv', 'csv2.csv', 'csv3.csv'].map((c) => {
    q.defer(d3.csv, c);
});

q.awaitAll(function(error, csv1, csv2, csv3) {
    csvOne = csv1[0];
    csvTwo = csv2[0];
    csvThree = csv3[0]
});

console.log(csvOne);
console.log(csvTwo);
console.log(csvThree);
```

Any idea how I can load multiple CSVs at once and assign each of them to separate arrays?

Cheers

**Edit to current code based on answer below**

```
var csvOne;
var csvTwo;
var csvThree;

var q = d3.queue();
    ['data/csv1.csv', 'data/csv2.csv', 'data/csv3.csv'].map((c) => {
});

q.awaitAll(function(error, [csv1 , csv2 , csv3]){
    csvOne = csv1;
    csvTwo = csv2;
    csvThree = csv3;
});

console.log(csvOne);
console.log(csvTwo);
console.log(csvThree);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to [`queue.await()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue#queue_await), which will pass the result of each deferred task as an additional argument to the callback, [`queue.awaitAll()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue#queue_awaitAll) passes an array of the results as the second argument to the callback.

The solution to your problem is to either use `.await()`:

```
q.await(function(error, csvOne , csvTwo , csvThree) {
    //...
});
```

Or, use `.awaitAll()` and get the individual results from that array:

```
q.awaitAll(function(error, [csvOne , csvTwo , csvThree]) {
    //...
});
```

But be aware of the infamous [*"How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?"*](/q/14220321). The way it is now will inevitably result in a follow-up problem.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I am using `.awaitAll()` and it's not separating the arrays? See my latest edit - variables `csvOne`, `csvTwo`, etc are logging to the console as undefined.

Comment: @dumbquestionsbydumbpeople: read the link supplied by altocumulus

Comment: So that was a long read, so essential return a callback function?

Comment: @dumbquestionsbydumbpeople Great, that this helped! If you still have issues with the asynchronous call, please post another question.